# Как получить id выделенной строки в DataGridView на C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, sqlite, datagridview

Салют! Стоит задача удалить по нажатию кнопки запись (SQLite), которая в данный момент выделена пользователем в гриде. Вопрос: как это можно грамотно сделать?

В данный момент у меня это выглядит так:

```
if (MessageBox.Show("Удалить запись? ", "Удаление записи", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Warning) == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                conn.Open();
                SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(@"DELETE FROM Treadmill WHERE name = @name", conn);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("name", dataGridView.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                conn.Close();
                MessageBox.Show("Запись удалена", "Удаление записи", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }
```

Сейчас это работает по полю `name` и удаляет только самую верхнюю строку в гриде. Можно ли как-нибудь получить номер выделенной строки в гриде, сравнивать его с полем `id` в базе и по нему удалить запись?

Спасибо за подробный ответ :)

P.S. Как грид заполняется данными. Код:

```
conn.Open(); // Открыть соединение
            // Заполнение таблицы
            SQLiteDataAdapter Adapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter(select_treadmill, conn);
            DataSet ds = new System.Data.DataSet();
            Adapter.Fill(ds, "Table");
            dataGridView.DataSource = ds.Tables["Table"].DefaultView;

            // Заполнение шапки таблицы
            dataGridView.Columns[0].Visible = false;
            dataGridView.Columns[1].HeaderText = "Назввание";
            dataGridView.Columns[2].HeaderText = "Дата";
            dataGridView.Columns[3].HeaderText = "Время, мин";
            dataGridView.Columns[4].HeaderText = "Скорость, км/ч";
            dataGridView.Columns[5].HeaderText = "Дистанция, км";
            dataGridView.Columns[6].HeaderText = "Калории, ккал";
            dataGridView.Columns[7].HeaderText = "Пульс, уд/мин";
            conn.Close(); // Закрыть соединение
```

Запрос:

```
string select_treadmill = "SELECT id, name, date, timer, speed, distance, calories, pulse FROM Treadmill";
```

Comment: Добавьте тег winforms к вопросу.

Comment: Для того чтобы ответить нужно знать как вы заполняете DGV данными.

Comment: @Bulson добавил

Comment: Обязательно нужно получать id из базы. Вернее, нужно получать уникальный ключ. Только он позволит безошибочно удалять/изменять строки.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov да мне хотя бы как-нибудь удалять

Comment: `DROP DATABASE`

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov ха-ха

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно так

```cshap
int index = dataGridView.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
```

Или так

```csharp
int index = dataGridView.SelectedRows[0].Index;
```

---

Разобрались с кодом, получилось следующее решение:

1) изменить запрос, чтобы приехал ключ `id`

```csharp
const string select_treadmill = "SELECT * FROM Treadmill";
```

2) спрятать первую колонку

```csharp
dataGridView.Columns[0].Visible = false;
```

3) удалять элемент по `id`, находящемуся в первой колонке

```csharp
private void deleteRecBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (dataGridView.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
    {
        if (MessageBox.Show("Вы действительно хотите удалить запись? Это действие нельзя будет отменить", "Удаление записи", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Warning) == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            string id = dataGridView.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
            conn.Open();
            SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(@"DELETE FROM Treadmill WHERE id = @id", conn);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("id", id);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();
            MessageBox.Show("Запись была успешно удалена из базы данных", "Удаление записи", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            FillingGrid();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Всё равно возвращается 0, а не выбранной строки, не понимаю почему :(

Comment: @Relzon оба способа возвращают 0?

Comment: Да, оба возвращают 0

Comment: @Relzon проверьте, настроено ли [это](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.selectionmode?view=netframework-4.8) и [это](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.multiselect?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: Вроде проверил всё. Сделал выделение всей строки, запретил выделение нескольких строк и всё равно возвращается пресловутый 0

Comment: @Relzon ну тогда я не знаю, чем помочь. Создайте обработчик события `SelectionChanged`, засуньте в него `MessageBox`, выкидывающий на экран текущее значение выделенной строки, полученное обоими способами, поставьте на него брейкпоинт, потыкайте по табличке, смотрите, что там в датагриде внтури в отладчике.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106910/discussion-between-relzon-and-aepot).

Comment: М-м-м... `Cells[0]` - там содержится `name`, если судить по запросу из вопроса. Я в чат не заглядывал, но вы там явно пришли к извлечению `id` из БД. Хорошо бы отредактировать вопрос - это я вам, @Relzon.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov а вот и нет, копия проекта у меня, и в первой колонке айдишники

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov `dataGridView.Columns[0].Visible = false;` вот еще я это предложил в чате

Comment: Повторяю: сейчас ваш ответ не отвечает на заданный вопрос. В вопросе указано `SELECT name`. Это не мои придирки, это требование нашего сайта: ответ должен **точно** отвечать на вопрос. Или автор должен отредактировать вопрос (но он, похоже, способен только на "ха-ха"), или вы укажите в ответе дополнительную информацию: как делается sql-запрос.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov так лучше?

Comment: Ох-х... Вы в курсе, что в приличном обществе за `select *` бьют ногами? :) PS: я понимаю, что так у автора. PPS: да, так лучше; пойдёт.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov я вас услышал.